# Traverse in an HTML element using the element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to write a condition based on the `style="display:none;"` as given below.

```
<div class="wrap hide" id="post_query" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

I want to find whether `style="display:none;"` is present or not.

My jQuery code is

```
if($("#post_query").hasClass("wrap", "hide").indexOf('display:none') !==-1) {
     console.log("Display None is present");
}
```

I am getting jQuery error.

Comment: If you get an error, include it in text format to your question so others searching with same error will find your question

Answer (score 1):

```js
if($("#post_query").css('display') == 'none'){
   console.log("Display None is present");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap hide" id="post_query" style="display:none;" >
</div>
```

it right Way

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('div').is('[style="display:none;"]')) {
```

Do you need it to be specific to the `display:none` or are you just checking for visible?

```
if (!$('div').is(':visible')) {
```

Comment: I have display:none at a specific moment and using that I want to write certain condition.

Comment: The `.is('[style="display:none;"]')` condition should what you need.